# How to convert MS Access OLE-Object to Attachment

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ole

we have to convert a old Access 2003 Database with OLE-Objects to Access 2007.
The biggest problem is, we don't want to use OLE anymore and change this to Attachment.

But i don't find any source how to do this.

I tried to use our SQL-Server to convert this (bad idea, i know ^^), but it returns only OLE-Object as data type.

The biggest problem with these old OLE-Objects is the need of the OLE-Server.

Hope, somebody have an idea how to solve our problem.

With best regards

Alexander

Answer (score 0):

See [OLE To Disk](http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm).   "This version saves the entire contents of a table containing OLE Objects to disk. Does NOT require the original application that served as the OLE server to insert the object."

Comment: OK, but how do i set these files as origin of attachment-fields?
Do i have to do it manually file per file in row per row? Or is their some kind of automatism?

Comment: That part I don't know as I haven't worked much with that feature in Access 2007.

Comment: Code can insert files to Attachment field, however, recommend not. Instead save filepath to text field. Either way, code would loop through folder and do something with each file - either embed in Attachment field or save filename to text field.